# Why the footprints of the identical Sentinel-2 image from GEE and SciHub are different?

Tags: google-earth-engine

The footprint of one Sentinel-2 tile (e.g., the image whose ID is "COPERNICUS/S2/20200702T023551_20200702T024443_T51RTQ") from [Scihub](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home) is rectangle, while that from GEE is polygon. How to explain this difference?

[image: footprint from SciHub]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there is a difference...If you visualize with `Map.addLayer(footprint)` it should be a rectangle. If you're asking why they store the shapes differently that would be a question that likely wouldn't fit the SE "single focused question" format.

Comment: Dear @rpr_mt. The footprint looks like a rectange, but actually it is a polygon.

Comment: I apologize, I guess I misunderstood your question. It seems like you are asking why the shape is stored differently (rectangle vs. polygon) across the different platforms, even though they cover the same area?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any idea on this issue? It's confusing that GEE stores  the rectangle as a polygon.

Comment: I do not, sorry for the miscommunication.This seems like more of a question for the EE Developer forum or something more directly tied to GEE. The page linked here has a link to the Developer Forum as well as some others that may be useful. https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help